# how to create a method who can be called by another class with dot notation

Tags: c#

explaining what i want to do with an example is easier
my method:

```
private void Update<T>(IInterface<T> provider, IEnumerable<T> models)
    {
        foreach (var model in models)
            provider.Update(model);
    }
```

how i call it

```
Update<ModelType>(_provider,models);
```

i want to use the dot notation like that but the method must be declared in this class and not in the provider class

```
_provider.Update<ModelType>(models);
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with [extensions methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). Method should be declared as `public static` in `public static` class and have first parameter preceded by the `this` modifier:

```
public static class MyExt
{
    public static void Update<T>(this IInterface<T> provider, IEnumerable<T> models)
    {
        foreach (var model in models)
            provider.Update(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Something like this should work:

```cs
public static class IInterfaceExtensions
{
    public static void Update<T>(this IInterface<T> provider, IEnumerable<T> models)
    {
        foreach (var model in models)
            provider.Update(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's important to mention that extension methods must be defined in a static class.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered this is achieved using extension methods. I know the technique as Extension Method Chaining.

[Extension Method Chaining Tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/6672/extension-methods-for-chaining)